# $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \Delta B_i^2\stackrel{ c.c. } \longrightarrow T $ for equally spaced interval?

Tags: convergence-divergence, brownian-motion

**{Q: [0, T] is spaced equally, as usual notation:$\Delta B_i=B_{t_i}-B_{t_{i-1}}$, $t_i-t_{i-1}=T/n$.
 Show $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \Delta B_i^2\stackrel{ c.c. } \longrightarrow T $}**

$Proof$: 
for all $\varepsilon$,

$\mathbb{P}\left(\{\omega\in \Omega:|\sum_{i=1}^{n} \Delta B_i^2-t|>\varepsilon\}\right)$

$\leq  {\frac{E(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\Delta B_i^2-t)^4}{\varepsilon^4}}$(by Markov inequality)

$=12T^4(1/n^2+4/n^4)=O(1/n^2)$ .

then $\sum \mathbb{P}\left(\{ \omega\in \Omega:|\sum_{i=1}^{n} \Delta B_i^2-T|>\varepsilon\}\right)$ is a convergent series, satisfying the definition of c.c. (complete convergence),

So $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \Delta B_i^2\stackrel{ c.c. } \longrightarrow T $, that also implies $a.s.$ (or by Borel-Cantelli lemma).

Is there any error I cannot find?  so it is appreciated if someone can point it out. wellcome for any comments, thanks so much.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! I noticed you've also posted the body of this question as an answer to two related questions [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1853219/quadratic-variation-of-brownian-motion-doesnt-converge-almost-surely) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59547/quadratic-variation-of-brownian-motion-and-almost-sure-convergence) (where it does not answer the questions asked). In future, you should stick to just asking a question, rather than asking people to confirm your work in answers of other questions.

Comment: ... and why do you post the same question two times? [This one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3129013/36150) is a clear duplicate

Comment: deleted the original already. thanks for pointing it out.